# PDE with inhomogeneous term $u_t + xu_x = x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the PDE: $u_t + xu_x = x^2$ with initial condition $u(x,0) =sinx$.

I am having difficulty solving this equation. I have tried the method of characteristics.

$dx/dt = x$ so I can get $x=ce^t$

$du/dt = x^2$ This I cannot figure out how to solve?

Comment: What is $\frac{du}{dt}$ supposed to mean here?  Should it be $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, or do you mean $\frac{d}{ds}u(x(s),t(s))$?

Answer (score 4):

The two characteristic equations you have found are

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= x \quad (1)\\
\frac{du}{dt} &= x^{2} \quad (2)
\end{align}

You found that the solution to $(1)$ is given by $x(t) = x_{0} e^{t} \implies x_{0} = xe^{-t}$. The solution to $(2)$ is given by

\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt} &= x^{2} \\
&= x_{0}^{2} e^{2t} \\
\implies \int \frac{du}{dt} dt &= \int x_{0}^{2} e^{2t} dt \\
\implies u(x(t), t) &= \frac{x_{0}^{2} e^{2t}}{2} + f(x_{0}) \\
&= \frac{x^{2} e^{-2t} \cdot e^{2t}}{2} + f(xe^{-t}) \\
&= \frac{x^{2}}{2} + f(xe^{-t})
\end{align}

which satisfies the PDE for arbitrary $f$. Applying the initial condition $u(x,0) = \sin x$ gives

\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= \frac{x^{2}}{2} + f(x) \\
&= \sin x \\
\implies f(x) &= \sin x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} \\
\implies f(xe^{-t}) &= \sin (xe^{-t}) - \frac{x^{2} e^{-2t}}{2} \\
\implies u(x(t), t) &= \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \sin (xe^{-t}) - \frac{x^{2} e^{-2t}}{2} \\
&= \frac{x^{2}}{2} \bigg( 1 - e^{-2t} \bigg) + \sin (xe^{-t})
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You already found that $x(t) = xe^t$.  It follows that $x^2 = C^2 e^{2t}$.  Thus, we are simply solving
$$
\frac{du}{dt} = C^2 e^{2t}
$$
we obtain the solution 
$$
u(t) = \frac {C^2}2 e^{2t} + D
$$
where $D \in \Bbb R$ is arbitrary.